# Convert copy-and-pasted XLS + CSV + HTML Table to JSON in Node or Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, json, node.js, csv

I've seen a lot of similar questions but none of the Node.js XML converters have worked for me at all. They've all garbled the data I've inputted and have gotten the parameters completely incorrect.

I'm trying to create something similar to this:

http://convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm

Basically, I want a textarea where a user can paste in spreadsheet data OR data copy-and-pasted from an HTML table and convert it into JSON. Reading XML or CSV files from the filesystem is not necessary, I just want the simplest too that will accept either XML, CSV or HTML table data, recognise how to interpret it and successfully convert it to JSON.

[Here's an example of what I mean when I say "Copy and pasted HTML tab data"](http://jsfiddle.net/hMu5r/)

"Copy and pasted XML/CSV" gets pasted out like this:

```
Name    Email   Topic
Bill    foo@bar.com topic1
Mary    test@test.com   topic2
Jane    moo@maa.com topic3
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried this https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson#example ?

Comment: Do you mean XLS or XML?  You used XLS in the title but XML in the question